# Other ways of sorting List<Date> in Codename One

Tags: java, codenameone

Due to Codename One [not implementing](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/why-we-dont-support-the-full-java-api.html) the full Java API, is there another working way of sorting List of Dates?

I've tried below, both of which failed to compile.

```
datesList.sort(Date::compareTo); // Failed
```

> error: invalid method reference datesList.sort(Date::compareTo);

```
// Failed
Collections.sort(datesList, new Comparator<Date>(){
    public int compare (Date d1, Date d2){
        return d1.compareTo(d2);
    }
});
```

> error: cannot find symbol return d1.compareTo(d2);

The same issue with getting the last day of the month with below:

```
cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DATE);
```

> error: cannot find symbol cal.set(Calendar.DATE, cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DATE));

Comment: Both the first and the second one works fine without any error [check the ideone demo](https://www.ideone.com/AWxfFu)!

Comment: In native Java, yes, but my question specifically refers to Codename One.

Comment: Looks like your second method should work, you just have to write your own comparison. Probably getting long values of dates and comparing those should be good enough.

Comment: Does Codename One implement java.time, the modern Java date and time API? The `Date` class is poorly designed and long outdated, so you should prefer `Instant` or another class from java.time if possible.

Comment: Yes, it does in its Calendar API. but `java.time` isn't available outside of that API. In this instance, I had to use `java.Date` which is returned from another Library I'm using. You actually gave me an idea. I will build my list using the `Calendar` API as it implements `compareTo`.

Comment: I'm wrong about CN1 using `java.time` in it's `Calendar` or `DateUtil` API. I believe this was because of these API's being around way before `java.time` was written.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest another soultion for sortig.You can use the connection sorting like:

```
dateList = 
    datesList
    .stream()
    .sorted( 
        Comparator.comparingLong( e -> e.getTime() ) 
    ).collect( 
        Collectors.toList() 
    );
```

if you has not stream change the comparing method to:

```
Collections.sort(datesList, new Comparator<Date>(){
    public int compare (Date d1, Date d2){
        return Long.compare( d1.getTime() , d2.getTime());
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Codename one doesn't have Stream package that has  Collectors.

Comment: As additional info, Codename One has the method: `DateUtil.compare(Date d1, Date d2)`

Comment: @Francesco Galgani, that's only good for comparing 2 dates and not a list of dates.